# How to send an email with nodemailer on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, lambda

I'm calling the following code ( with actual email addresses and passwords ) in my AWS Lambda function. Unfortunately, I'm unable to view the logs (my account currently doesn't have the permissions). Is there any specific permissions I have to set up to send an email from a lambda function? Or is there another/better way to send and email?

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'source@gmail.com',
      pass: 'paswword'
    }
  });

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'source@gmail.com',
    to: 'destination@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'That was easy!'
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work locally? I'd start with that. Your method might be not working because https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps feature is disabled.

Assuming you're using HTTP integration, if you cannot see logs, I'd create an array and instead of calling `console.log`, I'd append each log to that array. At the end of function, I would simply respond with `200` containing that logs.

You can also consider using https://aws.amazon.com/ses/. It's a cloud-based email sending service. It works great with AWS Lambda. In order to get it work, you need to add `ses:SendEmail` permissions and get through verification process.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Before diving into Amazon SES, will it allow me to send emails from my Lambda function with a method call?

Comment: Yep, here's an example how it's done: https://github.com/netguru/aws-iam-manager/blob/master/src/ses.js#L118. It's also in AWS Lambda environment.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that using AWS SES may incur additional charges. https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/

Comment: Great, I'll make sure to take a look into AWS SES, thanks for the advice